# Getting Values From Json Data Inside Array in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mariadb

We are saving information in a json Column which contain json data in an array.

Data structure:

```
[
    {
        "type":"automated_backfill",
        "title":"Walgreens Sales Ad",
        "keyword":"Walgreens Sales Ad",
        "score":4
    },
    {
        "type":"automated_backfill",
        "title":"Nicoderm Coupons",
        "keyword":"Nicoderm Coupons",
        "score":4
    },
    {
        "type":"automated_backfill",
        "title":"Iphone Sales",
        "keyword":"Iphone Sales",
        "score":3
    },
    {
        "type":"automated_backfill",
        "title":"Best Top Load Washers",
        "keyword":"Best Top Load Washers",
        "score":1
    },
    {
        "type":"automated_backfill",
        "title":"Top 10 Best Cell Phones",
        "keyword":"Top 10 Best Cell Phones",
        "score":1
    },
    {
        "type":"automated_backfill",
        "title":"Tv Deals",
        "keyword":"Tv Deals",
        "score":0
    }
]
```

What we are trying:

```
SELECT id, ad_meta->'$**.type' FROM window_requests
```

that returns:

[image]

We are looking to get each type as row, which i think only possible with stored procedure, return whole column and then run loop on each row and return data...

Or can you think of a better solution?

Either Update Architecture:

or should we change our database and save information in separate table instead to json column ?

And then we can get easily join to get data with adding a foreign key.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand that you are trying to generate a table structure from the content of your JSON array.

You would need to proceed in two steps :

- first, turn each element in the array into a record ; for this, you can generate an inline table of of numbers and use `JSON_EXTRACT()` to pull up the relevant JSON object.
- then, extract the values of each attribute from each object, generating new columns ; the `->` operator can be used for this.

Query :

```
SELECT 
    id,
    rec->'$.type' type,
    rec->'$.score' score,
    rec->'$.title' title,
    rec->'$.keyword' keyword                                   
FROM (
    SELECT t.id, JSON_EXTRACT(t.val, CONCAT('$[', x.idx, ']')) AS rec
    FROM 
        mytable t
        INNER JOIN ( 
            SELECT 0 AS idx    UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
            UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
        ) AS x ON JSON_EXTRACT(t.val, CONCAT('$[', x.idx, ']')) IS NOT NULL
    ) z
```

This will handle up to 10 objects per JSON array (if you expect more than that, you can add expand the `UNION ALL` part of the query).

In **[this DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nUzqyhrjiPnucWkemCGkBN/0)** with your test data, this yields :

```
| id  | type                 | score | title                     | keyword                   |
| --- | -------------------- | ----- | ------------------------- | ------------------------- |
| 1   | "automated_backfill" | 4     | "Walgreens Sales Ad"      | "Walgreens Sales Ad"      |
| 1   | "automated_backfill" | 4     | "Nicoderm Coupons"        | "Nicoderm Coupons"        |
| 1   | "automated_backfill" | 3     | "Iphone Sales"            | "Iphone Sales"            |
| 1   | "automated_backfill" | 1     | "Best Top Load Washers"   | "Best Top Load Washers"   |
| 1   | "automated_backfill" | 1     | "Top 10 Best Cell Phones" | "Top 10 Best Cell Phones" |
| 1   | "automated_backfill" | 0     | "Tv Deals"                | "Tv Deals"                |
```

NB : the arrow operator is not available in MariaDB. You can use `JSON_EXTRACT()` instead, like :

```
SELECT 
    id,
    JSON_EXTRACT(rec, '$.type') type,
    JSON_EXTRACT(rec, '$.score') score,
    JSON_EXTRACT(rec, '$.title') title,
    JSON_EXTRACT(rec, '$.keyword') keyword
FROM
    ...
```

Comment: but its not working for MariaDB ! i think because of arrow operator "->" ?

Comment: @FurqanFreed : yes it looks like the `->` is not supported in MariaDB, I updated my answer to provide an alternative using `JSON_EXTRACT()`